# How does Scheme return the "built up" value of a recursive procedure after the base case is met?

Tags: recursion, scheme, mit-scheme

I'm going through [Simply Scheme](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/simply-toc.html) and just got to the section on recursion.

I don't understand why when the base case is met Scheme returns the "built up" value of the recursive procedure and not the actual argument value which caused the base case to evaluate to `#t`.

For example, have a look at this sample code snippet of a recursive procedure which takes a word as input, reverses it, and spits it back out:

```
(define (reverse wd)
  (if (empty? wd) wd
      (word (last wd) (reverse (bl wd)))))
```

Here's what confuses me: `(if (empty? wd) wd`

I understand that when the actual argument value for the formal parameter `wd` is empty (or `""`) the base case evaluates to `#t`, causing the value of the second argument to `if` to be evaluated.

What I *don't* understand is how the second argument to `if` (`wd`, in this case) can return something that's not empty even though it would appear to be the same, empty, formal parameter that triggered the base case.

What am I missing?

If there's something in the documentation (or the text) which explains this I'd be happy to review it.

Comment: Just to be clear (and it may already be clear), the value of `(if test then-part else-part)` is `then-part` if `test` is true, and `else-part` if `test` is false.  So whenever `wd` is empty, you are returning `wd` (which is empty).  Whenever `wd` is _not_ empty, though, you're returning `(word (last wd) (reverse (bl wd)))`.  Do you see why that won't be empty when `wd` isn't empty? Even without considering `(reverse (bl wd))`, and just looking at `(word (last wd) …)` we see something non-empty since `(last wd)` is _something_ and `(word <something> …)` is a string beginning with `<something>`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - yes, I understand. Sylwester and Chris Jester-Young helped suss out the final point in below comments. Your contributions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since state doesn't change here you could just substitute what the function does with its recursion. Imagine you have a two letter word `a` :

```
(reverse a) ; =>
(word (last a) (reverse (bl a))) ; ==>
(word (last a) (word (last (bl a)) (reverse (bl (bl a))))) ; ==>
(word (last a) (word (last (bl a)) (bl (bl a)))) ; ==>
(word (last a) (word (last (bl a)) '()))
```

The last `(bl (bl a))` is the only thing done by the last iteration and it's `'()`.
The rest is done as the continuation of the previous calls.

**EDIT**

To clarify.. Imagine a is "ab"

```
(reverse "ab") ; turns into
(word (last "ab") (reverse (bl "ab")))           ; tuns into
(word "b" (reverse (bl "ab")))                   ; turns into 
(word "b" (reverse "a")))                        ; turns into 
(word "b" (word (last "a") (reverse (bl "a"))))) ; turns into
(word "b" (word "a" (reverse ""))))
```

Now look at that last one.. When `(reverse "")` returns "" it's the result used in the previous form call, in the `word` form, so you'll get `(word "a" "") ==> "a"`, then that will be returned to the first call that does `(word "b" "a")`. These are continuations.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have mental block. :) Specifically I'm just not seeing how the value of the first `wd` in `(empty? wd) wd` could be `'()` but the second isn't. Could you perhaps include something about that in your answer?

Comment: edit: I should have written `""` for empty word instead of `'()`.

Comment: @d3vin In the base case it's empty and the return is empty. `(reverse "") ==> ""`. The result for that would then be the second argument in the previous round. Thus "q" would have two iterations and end up as `(word (last "q" (reverse "")) => (word (last "q") "")`.

Comment: WRT this point: `The result for that would then be the second argument in the previous round.` I don't believe this "action" was explained in the text, thus I'm unaware of corresponding technical details or related terms. I believe now I could find a detailed technical explanation on my own (thanks, btw), but if you would like to add a "breadcrumb" or two to your answer it may be helpful to me and others in the future. :)

Comment: Reading about Scheme's reification of continuations is making this much more clear to me. I'm currently reading about continuations on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuations) and [scheme.com](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/further.html#g63). If you  know of a better resource feel free to let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The key insight is that it *is* returning empty for the base case. That's because the reverse of an empty string *is* an empty string.

The recursive cases actually work on that assumption. In words, here's how your `reverse` function works:

1. If the given word is empty, return empty.
2. Otherwise, take the last letter from the word, and join that with the reverse of the remainder of the word.

Example. Let's say we're reversing "Devin":

- The word "Devin" isn't empty, so we will join "n" with the reverse of "Devi".

  - The word "Devi" isn't empty, so we will join "i" with the reverse of "Dev".

    - The word "Dev" isn't empty, so we will join "v" with the reverse of "De".

      - The word "De" isn't empty, so we will join "e" with the reverse of "D".

        - The word "D" isn't empty, so we will join "D" with the reverse of "".

          - The word "" is empty, so we return "".
        - Here, we return "D" joined with "", which is "D".
      - Here, we return "e" joined with "D", which is "eD".
    - Here, we return "v" joined with "eD", which is "veD".
  - Here, we return "i" joined with "veD", which is "iveD".
- Here, we return "n" joined with "iveD", which is "niveD".

Comment: Juster-Young - visually this makes a lot of sense (thanks, btw). In response to @Sylwester's comment above I mentioned a lack of knowledge WRT what happens after (as per your answer) `The word "" is empty, so we return "".`. Is there something you could add to clear up this final point?

Comment: Then, you go up to the previous level, where I said _The word "D" isn't empty, so we will join "D" with the reverse of ""_, which as we've established, is "". Thus, the result of the previous level is "D" joined with "", which is "D".